# how to do input file name same as output file name (ffmpeg)

Tags: ffmpeg, video

```
ffmpeg -i "D:\aaaa\bbb\cccc\dddd\abc.ts" -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,18)),scale=200:100,tile=12x12" "D:\aaaa\bbb\cccc\dddd\tile.png"
```

I want to ask that how can I convert output file name as input file name automatically?

Example if video name abc.ts then image name must be abc.png

Comment: You cannot. ffmpeg won’t infer the output filenames in any circumstances

Comment: The tiitel is missliding, so @PierU commented that it's not possible. You want `abc.ts` to be `abc.png`, and it is possible. As far as I know there is no built in option in FFmpeg. We have to use shell capabilities, and the answer is going to be different for Windows and Linux (or MacOS). What is your operating system?

Comment: @Rotem I thought about what was his real question, and concluded that he was really inquiring about a ffmpeg built-in feature. This looks like an isolated command for a given file, and it's faster to type the input and output filenames explicitly rather than using an intermediate variable. If he had several files to be processed through a script, then the input file would be displayed as a variable here (and btw his OS is Windows, according to path style).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no built in option in FFmpeg, so we have to use an intermediate variable.

My answer assumes using Windows shell execution.

According to the [following post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26252288/4926757), when setting a variable and using it in the same line, we may have use `call` command to force a second parse on the line.

Example for using a variable:

`set p=tile&& call ffmpeg -i "D:\aaaa\bbb\cccc\dddd\%p%.ts" -frames 1 -vf "select=not(mod(n\,18)),scale=200:100,tile=12x12" "D:\aaaa\bbb\cccc\dddd\%p%.png"`

---

- `set p=tile` Creates environment variable `p` with value `tile`.
- `&&` is used for executing two commands in one line.
- `call` is required for making the two command executed in sequential order.
- `%p%` is replace with the value of the variable (replaced with `tile` in the example).

Comment: thanks too much rotem. have bad to meet with there not allowed automaticly named of files. anyway. but is there anything else of build exe etc. to do this about that. example like youtube-dl or anything else?

Comment: I never looked for this feature, and don't know about any exe. We can create a batch file that does that. FFmpeg is open source, so it is possible to edit the code and rebuild (I never tryed that)